# UIScollView and auto layout in Interface builder issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I decided to write new question on the topic after reading a lot of information here and there and trying to succeed with no results.

The task looks trivial. I have ScrollView. It has one subview of type UIView (let's call it ContentView). Content view, in turn, has 2 subviews of type UIView (let's call it ViewA and ViewB).

```
-ScrollView
    -ContentView
        -ViewA
        -ViewB
```

ScrollView has 4 constraints which bound it to all edges of superview. ViewA has 3 constraints (to ContentView) - top, left and right. ViewB has 4 constraints (to ContentView) - bottom, left, right and height. There is another constraint between bottom of ViewA and top of ViewB. The idea is that I will change the frame of ContentView at runtime, and ViewA and ViewB will be sized and layout accordingly and automatically.

Well, it does not work. I tried to put different constraint from ContentView to ScrollView, tried without them. Got different results, but none of them was correct. For example, ContentView has 4 constraints to ScrollView (top, bottom, left and right). I am setting the Frame of ContentView at runtime. However, it gets reset, and eventually, ContentView frame has basically the height of ViewB (which has height constraint).

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't set the frame of the content view.
2. You need to add a constraint to viewA in such a way that will define its height.

Comment: Am I adding it not that way? The height of ViewA should be automatically calculated based on the ContentView size and taking into account fixed height of ViewB. Otherwise, I do not understand the purpose of constraints in this example. For me, they should resize views at runtime. Otherwise, I can simply set all frames explicitly. There is also width of internal views. According to your words, I have to set it as well. But the idea is that I will set just one frame at runtime (of ContentView) and everything inside it will be layout accordingly

Comment: Using Auto Layout with a scrollView is definitely not intuitive and I would suggest reading Apple's technical note on the topic: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html Read the section "Pure Auto Layout Approach". You will be able to have dynamic layouts if you do it this way. The key thing to remember is that every view inside of the scrollView needs to either have explicit constraints that define its width/height or have an intrinsic size (like a UILabel).

Comment: Already read it multiple times. Trying to understand it. Eventually, I guess setting everything in IB is not an option.